# Pre-processor macro to convert an hex string to a byte array

Tags: c, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

I've defined an AES-128 key as a build symbol inside my IDE, so that it calls GCC like this:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -D"AES_KEY=3B7116E69E222295163FF1CAA1681FAC" ...
```

(which is equivalent to `#define AES_KEY 3B7116E69E222295163FF1CAA1681FAC`)

The advantage is that the same symbol can also be passed automatically as a parameter to a post-build CLI script that encrypts the compiled code with this key (e.g. for a secure firmware update)...

But how to store this key as a byte array in 
 my code?
I would like to define a pre-processor macro which does the conversion:

```
uint8_t aes_key[] = { SPLIT_MACRO(AES_KEY) };
```

to

```
uint8_t aes_key[] = {0x3B, 0x71, 0x16, 0xE6, 0x9E, 0x22, 0x22, 0x95, ...};
```

In other words, could the GCC pre-processor split the key string in 2-char blocks and add "`, 0x`" between them?

Comment: No. You should generate the source. The preprocessor can concatenate tokens but not split them, and it's altogether quite limited.

Comment: BTW: you mean `uint8_t aes_key[] = {0x3B, Ox71, 0x16, 0xE6, 0x9E, 0x22, 0x22, 0x95, ...}` (note the `[]`), right?

Comment: @StephanLechner indeed, just corrected it. thanks!

Comment: use any other tool (even another program in C ) to create an .h file, then compile. All in the makefile

Comment: Alternatively, you could split the string into integer sized chunks, or you could simply use the string as a string and parse it at runtime, saving  the individual bytes into an array. Unless you have many thousands of such strings, the few extra cycles spent at runtime shouldn't be noticable.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 good idea, like a pre-build CLI script. complexifies the setup a bit but it will work!

Comment: Or just a function, why don't you initialize the array in a function? You don;t need to allocate it dynamically.

Comment: @PSkocik sure, but the string takes twice the ROM size of the uint8_t array, plus the code to convert it and RAM to store the byte key. Not an ideal solution for an embedded device...

Comment: An alternative may be to set the parameter to a format more suitable for the C side (e.g. a string literal like `"\x3b\x71\x16..."`) and change the other post-build script to make it accept it.

Comment: @MatteoItalia great idea! had not thought about that. thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bit clumsy, but if you know the length of your key in advance you could approach it as follows:

1. define a macro `HEXTONIBBLE` that translates a hex digit into a number
2. define a macro `HEXTOBYTE` that uses `HEXTONIBBLE` to get a byte from a hex
3. initialize your array with `HEXTOBYTE` parameterized correctrly

If your `KEY` is not in form of a string, i.e. enclosed in double quotes, then use the stringify-operator `#` (with a trick using a variadic macro in order to expand a macro when used as parameter or another one):

```
//           01234567890123456789012345678901
#define K    3B7116E69E222295163FF1CAA1681FAC

#define STRINGIFY_HELPER(A) #A
#define STRINGIFY(...) STRINGIFY_HELPER(__VA_ARGS__)

#define KEY  STRINGIFY(K)

#define HEXTONIBBLE(c) (*(c) >= 'A' ? (*(c) - 'A')+10 : (*(c)-'0'))

#define HEXTOBYTE(c) (HEXTONIBBLE(c)*16 + HEXTONIBBLE(c+1))

uint8_t aes_key[] = {
    HEXTOBYTE(KEY+0),
    HEXTOBYTE(KEY+2),
    HEXTOBYTE(KEY+4),
    HEXTOBYTE(KEY+6),
    HEXTOBYTE(KEY+8),
    HEXTOBYTE(KEY+10),
    HEXTOBYTE(KEY+12),
    HEXTOBYTE(KEY+14),
    HEXTOBYTE(KEY+16),
    HEXTOBYTE(KEY+18),
    HEXTOBYTE(KEY+20),
    HEXTOBYTE(KEY+22),
    HEXTOBYTE(KEY+24),
    HEXTOBYTE(KEY+26),
    HEXTOBYTE(KEY+28),
    HEXTOBYTE(KEY+30)
};

int main() {

    for (int i=0; i<sizeof(aes_key); i++) {
        printf("%02X ", aes_key[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3B 71 16 E6 9E 22 22 95 16 3F F1 CA A1 68 1F AC
```

Comment: This works in C++ (although I'm not sure that the compiler is required to evaluate it at compile-time), but not in C: "test.c:13:22: error: initializer element is not constant".

Comment: @Matteo Italia: Hmm. for me it works: `gcc -std=c99 main.c -o main
./main
3B 71 16 E6 9E 22 22 95 16 3F F1 CA A1 68 1F AC` using clang/LLVM8.0.

Comment: https://ideone.com/pq3Zgy; same result on my machine with gcc 6.3; clang 4 instead compiles it fine. To me the error is not unexpected - operations involving strings (however known at compile time) have never been treated as constant values.

Comment: @StephanLechner awesome answer!!! took me a while to understand it, but it's exactly what I was looking for. thanks a lot for your help! unfortunately I have the same error than Matteo with GCC (error: initializer element is not constant). I guess it's because it don't like the KEY+x... Any workaround? Would it help if the key is surrounded by double quotes and we call K[x]?

Comment: You can make it work moving the array inside a function, to workaround the rule that is violated here (*All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.*, C99 §6.7.8 ¶4); again, notice that *in theory* this could delay the calculation at runtime (although in practice gcc resolves it completely at compile time).

Comment: Ok, so, checking the standard both gcc and clang are right; C99 §6.7.8 ¶4 mandates a constant expression for initialization of static storage duration objects (the idea being that their value should be baked straight into the executable); at §6.6 ¶7 it's explained that initializers require actually *arithmetic constant expressions* (or NULL or address constants +/- an integer constant expression); arithmetic constant expressions in turn may only contain integer/character/fp/enum constants and sizeof expressions as operands, so no string literals (which may be used in address constants, but ...

Comment: ... only to derive an address; no *actual* dereferencing is allowed). So, gcc is technically correct; clang's behavior is allowed as well, as ¶10 says that "An implementation may accept other forms of constant expressions.". However, relying on this of course makes the code non-portable.

Comment: does it work for 'odd' number of digits in the line?

Comment: @Serge: yes; one would have to adapt it then to `HEXTONIBBLE(KEY+0), HEXTOBYTE(KEY+1), HEXTOBYTE(KEY+3),...'

Comment: I made some tests today, seems that GCC doesn't resolve the byte array at compile time when declaration is made inside a function (Matteo's workaround). There is a 36 byte difference in the compiled binary... too bad :( I guess it's not possible with GCC, I marked this answer as accepted for C++ or other compilers. Thanks a lot for your help guys!

Answer (score 3):

This does not answer the original question but if the key can be written in this format instead:

```
#define AES_KEY 3B,71,16,E6,9E,22,22,95,16,3F,F1,CA,A1,68,1F,AC
```

The following macro will work, even under GCC:

```
#define BA(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p) {0x##a,0x##b,0x##c,0x##d,\
0x##e,0x##f,0x##g,0x##h,0x##i,0x##j,0x##k,0x##l,0x##m,0x##n,0x##o,0x##p}

#define TO_BYTEARRAY(...) BA(__VA_ARGS__)

uint8_t aes_key[] = TO_BYTEARRAY(AES_KEY);
```

See [Concatenation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html), [Argument Prescan](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Argument-Prescan.html) and [Variadic Macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html)

Comment: What is the reason for the variadic macro? Does it not work to directly do `BA(AES_KEY)`?

Comment: @kutschkem BA takes 16 arguments, while AES_KEY represents only one if we don't use the variadic macro.